# How to ensure user-input data is a specific data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have been working on some basic form validation in JavaScript. Currently, I have a simple HTML form that has three input fields - two requiring numerical input, and one requiring a string input. However, I am struggling to implement this.

```
const displayMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector(".message").textContent = message;
};

const displayOtherMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector(".message1").textContent = message;
};

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const height = Number(document.querySelector(".height").value);
  const weight = Number(document.querySelector(".weight").value);
  const name = String(document.querySelector(".name").value);
  if (!height && !weight && !name) {
    displayMessage("Please enter a height, a weight and a name.");
  } else if (!height || !weight || !name) {
    displayMessage("Please enter a height, a weight and a name.");
  } else if (height && weight && name) {
    if (
      typeof weight !== "number" ||
      typeof height !== "number" ||
      typeof name !== "string"
    ) {
      displayOtherMessage(
        "Height must be a number, weight must be a number and name must be a string."
      );
    }
    displayMessage("");
    alert(
      `Thank you, ${name}! You said you weigh ${weight} kilograms and are ${height} metres tall.`
    );
  }
});
```

Here is what I am struggling with:

```
 if (
      typeof weight !== "number" ||
      typeof height !== "number" ||
      typeof name !== "string"
    ) {
      displayOtherMessage(
        "Height must be a number, weight must be a number and name must be a string."
      );
    }
```

When I try to submit, say, "John" in the second input field, displayMessage is shown. How do I make it such that displayOtherMessage is shown instead?

HTML here:

https://pastebin.com/E5Pm6Dku

Comment: use required and pattern attributes, they are done for that

Comment: If you're not aware, HTML inputs are always strings, so to have JavaScript treat them as numbers, you need to convert them, probably with the global [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function. Also, it's better to include the relevant HTML here on Stack Overflow in a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than linking to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

`Number()` always returns a `number` and `String()` always returns a string, so those `typeof` checks don't do anything like what you seem to be hoping for.

If the string passed to `Number()` is an *invalid* number, it will return `NaN`. So you could try `isNaN(weight)` instead of `typeof`.

By the way, in the Node.js or browser console, you can experiment with this kind of thing directly, like do:

```
> var height = Number("john")
> height
NaN
> typeof height
"number"
> isNaN(height)
true
```

Try that also with a value that you want to be valid (like `"10"` or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit redundant in its checks. Such as, an `<input>` value will always be a string, so there is no need to check it's type, only that it isn't empty. Also, you should be more specific about what you need you user to do (which input is incorrect). You could simplify it to something like this:

```
const displayMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector(".message").textContent = message;
};

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let height = document.querySelector(".height").value,
      name = document.querySelector(".name").value,
      weight = document.querySelector(".weight").value;
  
  if (!name) {
    displayMessage("Please enter a name.");
  } else if (!height || isNaN(Number(height))) {
    displayMessage("Height must be a number.");
  } else if (!weight || isNaN(Number(weight))) {
    displayMessage("Weight must be a number.");
  } else {
    displayMessage(`Thank you, ${name}! You said you weigh ${weight} kilograms and are ${height} metres tall.`
    );
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1L5qjg2o/3/

Also, consider using the `keyup` event on your inputs to do these checks. In my opinion, it's a much better user experience if you do validation and corrections as the user is inputting them, rather than waiting until the very end when they go to submit everything and then have to go backwards.